# What RPC module works over SSH, telnet and HTTP?

Tags: python, rpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What RPC module should I use to implement RCP in Python and be able to change connection method later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430243/what-rpc-module-should-i-use-to-implement-rcp-in-python-and-be-able-to-change-co)

I am looking for RPC solution that can be used over different protocols like SSH, telnet and HTTP.

It has to be Python 2.5 compatible.

Comment: for the time being, check the docs on http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html , specially the "transport" parameter for ServerProxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely going to have to roll your own, but much of the heavy lifting in transport code could be done in other modules:

- [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) for ssh
- [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) for telnet
- [urllib(2)](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) for http.

You'll still have to address the issue of data format, but that is independent of transport protocol (feel free to deliver XML-RPC or JSON or any other format over these transports).

Comment: stdlib's xmlrpc client will do well for http - and it does support a "factory" to a "transport" object for the calls. It looks like it will be matter of creating a pair of client/server transport methods for telnet and ssh (paramiko) conformant to http.